# How to create an else statement with the expect command?

Tags: linux

I have the follow expect script which adds a known host if a known host does not exist.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh user@domain "cd /home/user"
expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"
send "yes\r"
interact
```

The script works fine the first time I ssh into a device however if I ssh into a device for a nth + 1 time, it throws an error

```
send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "yes\r""
    (file "./testing_spawn.sh" line 4)
```

presumably because it continues to expect the string `Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?`

How can I tell the script to just `interact` if that message does not show up?

Comment: I'm not familiar with expect, from what I saw [here][1] you can do like that: `expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" { send "yes\r" }`  [1]: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/

Answer (score 2):

Use `expect_before` to match the "unknown host" question only if it comes before the command prompt:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh user@domain
expect_before "*(yes/no)?" {
    send "yes\r"
}
expect "*# "
interact
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#./test.exp 1.1.1.1
```

test.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set ip [lindex $argv 0]

spawn ssh -q $ip
expect {
  timeout { send_user "\nFailed\n"; exit 1 }
  eof { send_user "\nSSH failure for $ip\n"; exit 1 }
  "Password:" {
    send "password\n"
  }
  "*(yes/no)?*" {
    send "yes\n"
    interact
  }
  "*#" {
    interact
  }
}
```